# Rails validates_uniqueness_of not working on MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running MySQL 5.7 and Rails 6. The problem is that Rails is permitting duplicates even though I am using `validates_uniqueness_of`.

So for example:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, if: :email_changed?
```

This will allow an email of USER@domain.com as well as user@domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know this option existed so I wanted to share with anyone else looking!

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false, if: :email_changed?
```